# ProFTPD with Postgres

Tags: postgresql, proftpd

Need Solution for below case.

I have configured ProFTPD with Postgres.
when client uploads file from Winscp , at server side

1. user get authenticated from PG table.
2. File get written on disk.
3. then same file name entry get insterted into PG.

Now at stage 3 if DB connection get lost,
There is SFTP session roll back.
and but no recovery at DB side when PG is up again by Proftpd.

https://www.howtoforge.com/proftpd_postgresql_auth_logging